# How to decode input for tx sent to zero address (contract creation tx)

Tags: solidity, transactions, json-rpc, abi, decoding

Decoding transaction input data requires providing ABI. How can I decode transaction input from a transaction issued to "zero" address? This special address is used for creating new contracts for which there is no ABI (I guess?).

Here's an example erc20 token creation transaction I ran on my local ganache node:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": {
        "hash": "0x73a5d7eb4f220e22c7a69a43e758a749b94c7c9fbbe4fcc25e522fc98d3afd1b",
        "nonce": "0x0",
        "blockHash": "0x5a287af0a81a21b380eeadaecb6c275ce556df64f2902c96a7c198f910c8acd9",
        "blockNumber": "0x1",
        "transactionIndex": "0x0",
        "from": "0x3c13963ac52d093e2a5f079c3c78d98b57f7bd79",
        "to": null,
        "value": "0x0",
        "gas": "0x6691b7",
        "gasPrice": "0x4a817c800",
        "input": "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",
        "v": "0x26",
        "r": "0xcc7b48ccce1d12ed42c393c747d57e43e1a6b6d175acddfb3e66a635c936b831",
        "s": "0x6653cbb895e2bb63a3a43298279cc4154c04d076b6933ae9e67a47a08d3776a3"
    }
}
```

How do I decode:

```
"input": "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"
```

Comment: The input (or data field) contains the contract's deployement bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

I hacked at it a little bit. You can find some data that makes sense and work backwards.

echo -n $input | xxd -p -r | strings | more
echo -n $input | xxd -p -r | grep ERC20
Interesting text:
ERC20: mint to the zero address
ERC20: transfer to the zero addr `ERC20: approve to the zero addre`
ERC20: transfer amount exceeds b `ERC20: transfer amount exceeds a`
ERC20: transfer from the zero ad `ERC20: approve from the zero add`
ERC20: decreased allowance below`

So then you just try to figure out a way to iterate through each of those, expand boundaries, turn stuff into fields. PHP and bash are my main toolkits. It takes time, but if you have lots of transactions, you can figure it out.